# No enclosing instance of type fbMain is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type fbMain

Tags: java

So in my class declared as "**public class pcb**", I have the following constructor: **public pcb(int p, int a, int b).**

In **public static void main(String[] args)** I try to call the constructor in a for loop where I add a "pcb" into a different position in an array. Here is the for loop where the last line is where I get the error:

```
for(int i=0; i<numJob; i++){
   pI = scan.nextInt();
   arr = scan.nextInt();
   bst = scan.nextInt();
   notHere[i]=new pcb(pI, arr, bst);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it syntax or is it the structure of my program. I haven't used Java that much and I think that's my main problem.

Comment: You forgot to show us the `pcb` class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't given all of the relevant code, but the error indicates that `pcb` is an inner class of `fbMain`:

```
public class fbMain {
    //...
    public class pcb {
    }
    //...
}
```

You can fix this error by making `pcb` static:

```
 public static class pcb {
 }
```

Or by moving the class to its own file.  Or, if `pcb` cannot be static (because it is associated with an instance of `fbMain`), you can create a new `pcb` by passing an instance of `fbMain`:

```
notHere[i] = instanceOfFbMain.new pcb(pI, arr, bst);
```

It is likely the first that you want.  Please also note that by convention, Java type names start with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 3):

Add `static` to your class declaration like this

```
public static class pcb...
```